# Why isn't scons using CCFLAGS in env variable?

Tags: scons

I have this SConstruct file:

```
env=Environment()
env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['-std=c99', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-g'])
print env["CCFLAGS"]


#Program('test_array.c',CCFLAGS=['-std=c99', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-g'],
                                                   CPPPATH = '.', LIBS='stuff', LIBPATH=".")

#Program('test_array.c',CPPPATH = '.', LIBS='stuff', LIBPATH=".")
```

The output from uncommenting the first Program() is:

```
scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o test_array.o -c -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -I. test_array.c
gcc -o test_array test_array.o -L. -lstuff
scons: done building targets.
```

The output from uncommenting the second Program() is:

```
scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o test_array.o -c -I. test_array.c
test_array.c: In function 'test_insert':
test_array.c:85:4: error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
test_array.c:85:4: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
```

The env variable has a value for CCFLAGS but I don't know why it isn't being used when not explicitly specified in the Program() call.

Comment: Related: how to pass compilation flags on the  command line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929011/how-to-pass-arbitrary-compiler-cflags-with-scons-from-the-command-line-without-c/56233309#56233309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Program() builder is taking the construction variables from the DefaultEnvironment(), not from the env you created. This behavior is described [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x1444.html#AEN1556).

Try the following:

```
env=Environment()
env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['-std=c99', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-g'])
print env["CCFLAGS"]

# Program() will take the construction vars from env, not the DefaultEnvironment()
#env.Program('test_array.c',CCFLAGS=['-std=c99', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-g'],
                                                   CPPPATH = '.', LIBS='stuff', LIBPATH=".")

#env.Program('test_array.c',CPPPATH = '.', LIBS='stuff', LIBPATH=".")
```

Notice I call the Program() builder on the `env` you created and modified.

So, all you really need is the second call, as follows:

```
env=Environment()
env.Append(CCFLAGS = ['-std=c99', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-g'])
print env["CCFLAGS"]

# Program() will take the construction vars from env, not the DefaultEnvironment()
env.Program('test_array.c',CPPPATH = '.', LIBS='stuff', LIBPATH=".")
```

Comment: or doing DefaultEnvironment().Append(CCFLAGS ....) That way you can keep your builder calls to Program clean (I mean without env. in front), in case you only need one build environment.