# How to pass arbitrary compiler CFLAGS with Scons from the command line without custom code?

Tags: scons

Is there a way to write something like:

```
scons CFLAGS='-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=thread'
```

which would just work with a minimal script:

```
env = Environment()
env.Program(target='main.out', source=['main.c'])
```

without changing that script?

I know how to do it by modifying the script with `AddOption` + `env.Append(CCFLAGS` but I'm wondering it it is possible without changing the code to explicitly support it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible by design (without explicitly changing the build scripts). From the answer to #1 of the most-frequently-asked questions in our [FAQ](https://scons.org/faq.html):

> SCons does not automatically propagate the external environment used
> to execute 'scons' to the commands used to build target files. This is
> so that builds will be guaranteed repeatable regardless of the
> environment variables set at the time scons is invoked. This also
> means that if the compiler or other commands that you want to use to
> build your target files are not in standard system locations, SCons
> will not find them unless you explicitly set the PATH to include those
> locations.

Comment: I don't need it to be with external environment variables, I would rather do it with `scons` command line options like `scons A=B`. Or are the two always related?

Comment: Calling simply `env = Environment()` will always result in a clean build environment. You'd then have to add/change variables to `env` such that your actual build environment is setup correctly. I don't know a way around this, there is no *bypass* method that would work automagically for some set of "special" variables. And it would work against the above described goal of making the build repeatable under all conditions, for these "specials". So, if there exists a way that I don't know of, it has to be considered a bug. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up going with:

```
env = Environment()
env.Append(CCFLAGS='-Werror')
env.Append(CCFLAGS=ARGUMENTS.get('CCFLAGS', ''))
env.Program(target='main.out', source=['main.c'])
```

which can be used as:

```
scons CCFLAGS='-Wall -pedantic'
```

and will compile as:

```
gcc -o main.o -c -Werror -Wall -pedantic main.c
```

You likely want to keep the `env.Append(CCFLAGS=ARGUMENTS.get('CCFLAGS', ''))` line as the very last change made to `CCFLAGS`, since this will allow overriding the defaults on the command line: GCC tends to just use the last value seen as the actual one.

TODO: how to make it work with Variables? This would be nicer since we can get more error checking and the help message generation:

```
variables = Variables(None, ARGUMENTS)
variables.Add('CCFLAGS', 'my help', '')
env = Environment(variables)
env.Append(CCFLAGS='$CCFLAGS')
env.Append(CCFLAGS=['-Werror'])
env.Program(
    source=['main.c'],
    target='main.out',
)
Help(variables.GenerateHelpText(env))
```

but this fails due to bad quoting:

```
gcc -o main.o -c "-Wall -pedantic" -Werror main.c
```